# “System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range” when executing LINQ to sharepoint query

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010, argumentexception

```
    var updateItem = (from item in ctx.LI_MyList
              where
              item.Id == 1
              select item).First();
```

I got the following exception when executing the query:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.

However `InsertOnSubmit ()` is working,
I tried the query with `LINQPad` but I got the same exception, here is `LINQPad StackTrace`:

The same list is responding normaly to CAML queries,

The same query is running normaly on other lists in the same site,

I Googled the exception but it seems to be caused by various reason.

Excuse my English and feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score -1):

Is there an item with ID equal to 1?

If not your query will not return results and the .First() function will fail.

If possible try the FirstOrDefault() function but you will need an extra test to check if your 'updateitem' variable is not null.

Comment: yes I already ionserted items, LI_MyList.Count() is returning 4,
from item  in LI_MyList
where item .Id == 1 
select item 

this query in LINQPad is returning the same exception.
Thanks for the quick replay.

Comment: I figured it out, one of the fields was causing the problem.

Comment: I've run into this problem as well. I think this is a bug with the WorkflowStatus column. Be sure to exclude column that in the SPMetal parameter file. Here's a useful link...

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1c00419a-f616-4556-8098-545f82ff1a3f/